# Redirect all image links to a folder on a different server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I currently have an `/img/` folder on my server, http://www.example.com. I would like to move those files over to https://secure.example.com, but by simply moving the folder a lot of links in my code would break and be linking to dead image locations.

Is there a way, with `.htaccess` or something else, to be able to force the server to look for images somewhere else wherever it finds a link to the original `/img/` folder?

i.e. When a page looks for http://www.example.com/img/test.jpg it actually looks at https://secure.example.com/img/test.jpg.

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ https://secure.example.com/img/$1 [NC,P]
```

Comment: What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: The redirect... I just get broken images.